# Compiling MatConvNet on Windows

Tags: windows, matlab, makefile, compiler-errors, matconvnet

I am trying to compile [MatConvNet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/) on Windows 8.1. Since it seems that I need to use the "Makefile" to do that, I downloaded [GNUWin Make](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), which allows to use the *make* command on Windows. The error I get is the following one:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\mexext, ...) failed.
```

while the file `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\mexext.bat` exists.

Do you have any clue on that please?

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to compile MatConvNet on Windows with MinGW and I faced the same error.
Instead, you can try to compile MatConvNet using Visual Studio. It is explained here:
http://blog.csdn.net/zxd675816777/article/details/40075209

With the translation from Chrome browser, it is understandable :)
Thanks to this tutorial, I successfully generated the 4 mexw64 files needed by MatConvNet.

Answer (score 1):

in the new beta-8 we have added new function `vl_compilenn` which supports compilation on Windows... (no need for Make, plus we've fixed the issues related to msvc compiler). So far it seems to work also for the GPU code...

You can find detail [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/). Hope that this would help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it using Visual Studio rather than GNU compiler on Windows. First set up Matlab mex -setup C++ for Visual Studio 2013/2015 and then compile using vl_compilenn function. If you want to compile it for GPU then you need to install CUDA and cudnn as well. Then you can use vl_compilenn('enableGpu', true) to compile it for Windows with GPU support.