# Multithreaded (pthreads) MATLAB mex function causes MATLAB to crash after exiting

Tags: c, multithreading, matlab, pthreads, mex

I have a task that I need to perform in MATLAB many times, and I would like to reduce the amount of time taken to perform the task by using a multithreaded MEX function. However, I'm running into a little snag where the MEX function causes MATLAB to crash after exiting due to a double free or corruption error.

The task itself is quite large, but I have been able to reproduce the error with the following minimum (non)working example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

/* hard coded number of matrices to create per thread */
int num_mat = 10;

/* struct for passing information to the thread */
typedef struct {
    int pnum;
    int num_mat;
    mxArray *outMatrix;
} pt_info_t;


/* thread function */
void *doThread(void *tinfo){

    /* extract info from the struct */
    pt_info_t pinfo = *((pt_info_t *)tinfo);
    mxArray *outMatrix = pinfo.outMatrix;

    /* create a cell matrix */
    mxArray *one_cell = mxCreateCellMatrix(pinfo.num_mat, 1);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < pinfo.num_mat; i++){
        /* fill the cell matrix with 1x1 double matrices */
        mxArray *one_mat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
        mxSetCell(one_cell, i, one_mat);
    }

    /* add the cell matrix to the return cell matrix */
    mxSetCell(outMatrix, pinfo.pnum, one_cell);

    /* exit the thread */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/* thread entry function */
void t_comp_routine(int num_threads, mxArray *outMatrix){

    /* thread setup */
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    pt_info_t pinfo[num_threads];

    /* add information to the thread info structs and start threads */
    int pnum = 0;
    for(pnum = 0; pnum < num_threads; pnum++){
        pinfo[pnum].pnum = pnum;
        pinfo[pnum].num_mat = num_mat;
        pinfo[pnum].outMatrix = outMatrix;

        pthread_create(&threads[pnum], NULL, doThread, (void *)(pinfo + pnum));
    }

    /* join the threads */
    for(pnum = 0; pnum < num_threads; pnum++){
        pthread_join(threads[pnum], NULL);
    }


}

/* same routine but without threads */
void comp_routine(int num_pretend_threads, mxArray *outMatrix){

    int pnum = 0;
    for(pnum = 0; pnum < num_pretend_threads; pnum++){
        mxArray *one_cell = mxCreateCellMatrix(num_mat, 1);

        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < num_mat; i++){
            mxArray *one_mat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
            mxSetCell(one_cell, i, one_mat);
        }

        mxSetCell(outMatrix, pnum, one_cell);
    }
}

/* The gateway function 
* nlhs = NUM left hand side args (OUTPUT)
* nrhs = NUM rhs args (INPUT)
* plhs = array of output args (OUTPUT)
* prhs = array of input args (INPUT)
*/
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{    
    int num_threads = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    mxArray *outMatrix = mxCreateCellMatrix(num_threads, 1);

    /* t_comp_routine causes matlab to crash after exiting */
    t_comp_routine(num_threads, outMatrix);

    /* comp_routine does not */
    /* comp_routine(num_threads, outMatrix); */

    plhs[0] = outMatrix;
    printf("Finished!\n");
}
```

The program takes in a `num_threads` variable and outputs a cell array with the same number of elements as there are threads. Each cell of the output array is a cell matrix of length 10, with each element of that containing a 1x1 double matrix.

Calling the function with 10 threads causes the following:

```
>> thread_test(10)
Finished!
ans = 
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
    {10x1 cell}
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00002b89a000cf10 ***
```

I have excluded the Backtrace for brevity, but I am more than happy to provide it if required.

Occasionally, calling the function with less than 10 threads will complete  without showing an error, although I suspect that there may still be a problem. The non threaded function `comp_routine` performs the same task and has run many times without error.

I believe the error may be as a result of creating mxArrays inside the thread function, but I don't know how to remedy this as with the full program I would have to create these arrays on the fly (I don't always know ahead of time what size to create them for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MEX API (includes the `mx*` functions) is [NOT thread safe (MathWorks Support Team)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101658#answer_111006). You can only call mx*/mex* functions from the main MATLAB thread, with a few exceptions (see bottom).  In `doThread`, which is launched with `pthread_create`, you are calling several functions that can't be used there:

- `mxCreateCellMatrix`
- `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`
- `mxSetCell`

You will have to pass plain-old-data in and out of `doThread` and manage the cell array outside of the threads called with `pthread_create`.  In addition to the [example from MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101658#answer_111006), which demonstrates using the Windows API for multithreading, another nice example of multithreading a MEX function using both Pthreads and the Windows API is provided by Dirk-Jan Kroon in [his tutorial on the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21233-mex-multithreading) and [his non-rigid registration submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21451-multimodality-non-rigid-demon-algorithm-image-registration), among others.  It may also be worth checking out the C++11 approach using `std::thread` in the [MexThread submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38034-mexthread).

Exceptions (YMMV): [`mexErrMsgIdAndTxt`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part3).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise I couldn't even use `printf` in a thread. Thanks for providing an example as well.

Comment: @agnussmcferguss There are some exceptions, and that might be one of them.  I can't remember where I read that though...

Comment: Oh okay, I was taking that information from the MathWorks Support Team answer: "no MEX API functions can be used in the spawned threads including printf because printf is defined to be mexPrintf in the mex.h header file".

Comment: @agnussmcferguss That is correct, [it is an alias.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27391388/2778484).  :)  What I mean is that although MathWorks officially says **no** MEX API functions, there are some that have been made thread-safe and `mexPrintf` might be one, despite their official answer.  Anyway, you can always use `printf_s` or something like that, but it won't print anyway because there's no visible stdout.

Comment: @agnussmcferguss Which reminds me, you can put `#undef printf` after `#include "mex.h" ` if you want the one from stdio.h, but again it probably won't print anything into the MATLAB command window.

Comment: Thanks - I think for now I'll "assume" that `mexPrintf` is thread safe and test the waters with that. If I run into any problems I'll just comment it out. I really only want it there for testing purposes anyway.

Comment: @chappjc - I should have known that.  In fact, I remember reading one of your answers that talks about this very fact. +1.